# I want to draw route from 1 point to other, but i get this error "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0" where is the fault?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, routes

i want to draw route from one point to other than i try to follow this tutorial https://medium.com/@rizal_hilman/bermain-google-maps-api-android-kuy-bikin-aplikasi-kayak-go-jek-belajarapi-20b004d6abdf but i get this error "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0"

ojekActivity.java

```
public void onResponse(Call<ResponseRoute> call, Response<ResponseRoute> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    // tampung response ke variable
                    ResponseRoute dataDirection = response.body();

                    LegsItem dataLegs = dataDirection.getRoutes().get(0).getLegs().get(0);

                    // Dapatkan garis polyline
                    String polylinePoint = dataDirection.getRoutes().get(0).getOverviewPolyline().getPoints();
                    // Decode
                    List<LatLng> decodePath = PolyUtil.decode(polylinePoint);
                    // Gambar garis ke maps
                    mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(decodePath)
                            .width(8f).color(Color.argb(255, 56, 167, 252)))
                            .setGeodesic(true);

                    // Tambah Marker
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pickUpLatLng).title("Lokasi Awal"));
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(locationLatLng).title("Lokasi Akhir"));
                    // Dapatkan jarak dan waktu
                    Distance dataDistance = dataLegs.getDistance();
                    Duration dataDuration = dataLegs.getDuration();

                    // Set Nilai Ke Widget
                    double price_per_meter = 250;
                    double priceTotal = dataDistance.getValue() * price_per_meter; // Jarak * harga permeter

                    tvDistance.setText(dataDistance.getText());
                    tvPrice.setText(String.valueOf(priceTotal));
                    /** START
                     * Logic untuk membuat layar berada ditengah2 dua koordinat
                     */

                    LatLngBounds.Builder latLongBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                    latLongBuilder.include(pickUpLatLng);
                    latLongBuilder.include(locationLatLng);

                    // Bounds Coordinata
                    LatLngBounds bounds = latLongBuilder.build();

                    int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                    int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
                    int paddingMap = (int) (width * 0.2); //jarak dari
                    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, width, height, paddingMap);
                    mMap.animateCamera(cu);

                    /** END
                     * Logic untuk membuat layar berada ditengah2 dua koordinat
                     */
                    // Tampilkan info panel
                    infoPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    mMap.setPadding(10, 180, 10, 180);

                }
            }
```

Comment: It looks like you don't take into account that service might return a ZERO_RESULTS status. In this case the `dataDirection.getRoutes()` is empty, so you cannot use expression `dataDirection.getRoutes().get(0)`, because it throws exception.

Comment: so how to fix it?

Comment: ooh yeah, this is the reetrofit code https://pastebin.com/7ATTyERc  Thank You